# Reading excel sheet which keeps on changing every milisecond and producing the same sheet in tabular form on Java gui

Tags: java

I have written the code and it's reading the Excel sheet and producing sheet on Java gui but it keeps on fliking.
As the data sheet are not showing in proper way it keeps on flicking on timer event.

My code is:

```
package com.trading.gui;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class ReadExcelFile extends TimerTask {
    static JTable table = new JTable();
    static JFrame f = new JFrame();
    static DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    static JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    static Vector headers = new Vector();
    static Vector data = new Vector();

    public void run() {

        String excelFilePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OnTime\\OnTime.Net\\OnTime.xls";
        final FileInputStream inputStream;
        final Workbook workbook;

        try {   
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFilePath);
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            final org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            headers.clear();
            data.clear();
            Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet1.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                System.out.println("while->" + nextRow.getRowNum());

                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

                final Vector d = new Vector();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    if (nextRow.getRowNum() == 0)
                        headers.add(cell.getStringCellValue().toString());
                    else
                        d.add(cell.getStringCellValue().toString());
                }
                d.add("\n");
                data.add(d);
            }

            workbook.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8538648271391086030L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        table.setModel(model);

        scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        // scroll.setLayout((LayoutManager) table);
        f.add(scroll);
        f.setSize(900, 700);
        f.setResizable(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

I want the output on Java gui screen in a proper way and not in flicking way. Hoping for the response.

Comment: Every millisecond seems like a lot.

Comment: yes its a Trading live  data which are changing very fast.

Comment: Are you recreating the screen every time? That would flicker - create the screen once and update the components. Also, separate your millisecond data reading from your screen update and update the screen every 100ms or so. No one can read millisecond updates in any case.